# Why Send requires Sync in this case?

Tags: rust

On this very simple example, I require `OnConsume` to be a `Send` function so I can send it to threads.

```
use std::sync::Arc;

trait EncodedPacket {}

pub type OnConsume = Arc<dyn Fn() -> Option<Box<dyn EncodedPacket>> + Send>;

pub trait Decoder: Send{}

pub struct DummyDecoder {
    pub on_consume: Option<OnConsume>,
}

impl Decoder for DummyDecoder {}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ed6427f3f1fb15a04d0f3354a957679f)

I'm getting this error about `Sync` though.

Error:

```
error[E0277]: `(dyn Fn() -> Option<Box<(dyn EncodedPacket + 'static)>> + Send + 'static)` cannot be shared between threads safely
  --> src/lib.rs:14:6
   |
7  | pub trait Decoder: Send
   |                    ---- required by this bound in `Decoder`
...
14 | impl Decoder for DummyDecoder {
   |      ^^^^^^^ `(dyn Fn() -> Option<Box<(dyn EncodedPacket + 'static)>> + Send + 'static)` cannot be shared between threads safely
   |
   = help: the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `(dyn Fn() -> Option<Box<(dyn EncodedPacket + 'static)>> + Send + 'static)`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Send` for `Arc<(dyn Fn() -> Option<Box<(dyn EncodedPacket + 'static)>> + Send + 'static)>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `Option<Arc<(dyn Fn() -> Option<Box<(dyn EncodedPacket + 'static)>> + Send + 'static)>>`
note: required because it appears within the type `DummyDecoder`
  --> src/lib.rs:10:12
   |
10 | pub struct DummyDecoder {
```

Why is it that it requires `Sync` for `(dyn Fn() -> Option<Box<(dyn EncodedPacket + 'static)>> + Send + 'static)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the docs for `Arc` you will see:

```rust
impl<T> Send for Arc<T>
where
    T: Sync + Send + ?Sized,
```

That is, `Arc<T>` implements `Send` only when `T` implements `Sync` as well. Here's why: if you put something in an `Arc`, clone the `Arc`, and *send* the clone to another thread, then the thing is now *shared* between those two threads — and therefore must be required to be `Sync`.

You *can* put a non-`Sync` type in an `Arc` — there's no trait bound that prevents this — but you can't ever send such an `Arc`. That's why the compiler attributes this to the `impl Decoder for DummyDecoder` rather than something else:

1. You write `impl Decoder for DummyDecoder {}`,
2. which requires `DummyDecoder: Send` because of the supertrait,
3. which requires `Option<OnConsume>: Send` because of the struct field,
4. which requires `Arc<dyn Fn() -> Option<Box<dyn EncodedPacket>> + Send>: Send`,
5. which requires `(dyn Fn() -> Option<Box<dyn EncodedPacket>> + Send): Sync` because of the bounds on `impl Send for Arc`,
6. which is false, because `Sync` isn't in the list of traits of the `dyn` trait object.

So, you need to add `+ Sync` to your `dyn Fn` (or wrap it in a `Mutex` if you don't want to require the function to do its own thread-safety).

In general, when you want thread-safety, these sets of trait bounds for functions make sense:

- `Fn() + Send + Sync`
- `FnMut() + Send`
- `FnOnce() + Send`

It's still *possible* to send `Fn + Send` across threads and call it, but since the point of `Fn` is to be shareable, you might as well include the `Sync` bound and make it shareable across threads, unless there's some particular reason the actual functions are likely to be obligated to be `!Sync` — in which case you should consider making them also `FnMut`, to give the functions opportunity to take advantage of their non-sharedness.